# Использование библиотеки FFTW (быстрое преобразование Фурье)

Tags: c#

Мне надо использовать библиотеку FFTW.  [Сайт с примером](http://www.sdss.jhu.edu/~tamas/bytes/fftwcsharp.html). 
Я написал код, основанный на примере с сайта. Мне надо с помощью БПФ получить АЧХ синусоидального сигнала. 
Входные данные - комплексные значения. Поэтому используется массивы

```
double[] fin, fout;
```

в которых fin[i*2] - действительное число, fin[i * 2 + 1] - мнимое число. Но как я понял т.к. у меня синусоидальный сигнал то мнимая часть должна быть равна нулю, т.е.
fin[i * 2 + 1] = 0

Я написал следующий код:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using fftwlib;

namespace fure
{
public class fftwtest
{
    //pointers to unmanaged arrays
    IntPtr pin, pout;

    //managed arrays
    double[] fin, fout;

    //pointers to the FFTW plan objects
    public IntPtr fplan1, fplan2;

    // Initializes FFTW and all arrays
    // n: Logical size of the transform
    public void InitFFTW(int n)
    {
        //create two unmanaged arrays, properly aligned
        pin = fftwf.malloc(n * 8);
        pout = fftwf.malloc(n * 8);

        //create two managed arrays, possibly misalinged
        //n*2 because we are dealing with complex numbers
        fin = new double[n*2];
        fout = new double[n*2];

        double T = 0.0000159;//длительность сигнала
        double F = 345000; //частота сигнала
        double F_d = 6250000;//частота дискретизации

        n = (int)(T * F_d);

        //fill our arrays with a sawtooth signal
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            fin[i*2] = 5 * Math.Sin(2 * Math.PI * F * i/F_d);
            fin[i * 2 + 1] = 0;
        }
        //copy managed arrays to unmanaged arrays
        Marshal.Copy(fin, 0, pin, n*2 );

        //create a few test transforms
        fplan1 = fftwf.dft_1d(n, pin, pout, fftw_direction.Forward, fftw_flags.Estimate); 
    }
    // Tests a single plan, displaying results
    //plan: Pointer to plan to test
    public void TestPlan(IntPtr plan, int n)
    {
        fftwf.execute(plan);

        Marshal.Copy(pout, fout, 0, n * 2);
        Console.WriteLine(fout[30]);
    }
    // Releases all memory used by FFTW/C#
    public void FreeFFTW()
    {
        //it is essential that you call these after finishing
        //may want to put the initializers in the constructor
        //and these in the destructor
        fftwf.free(pin);
        fftwf.free(pout);
        fftwf.destroy_plan(fplan1);
    }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        double T = 0.0000159;//длительность сигнала
        double F_d = 6250000;//частота дискретизации
        int n = (int)(T * F_d);

        fftwtest test = new fftwtest();
        test.InitFFTW(n);
        test.TestPlan(test.fplan1, n);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
}
```

Выходной массив fout. Но в этом массиве получаются какие то огромные значения, при возведении которых в квадрат получается бесконечность.

Где может быть ошибка?

Comment: malloc, free, маршаллинг - интерфейс у этой библиотеки даже и не пытается быть похожим на дотнетовский.

Comment: что это значит?

Comment: Когда что-либо переносят, то стараются сделать использование наиболее удобным именно на конечной платформе/языке. В данном случае необходимость создания неуправляемых массивов (pin, pout) видится излишней, с их отсутствием ушли бы также вызовы malloc(), free(), Marshal.Copy().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Кажется я нашел ошибку. Надо использовать не double,а float как в примере. Значения получается равными не больше 1000

Comment: Это хороший пример того, как легко ошибиться при работе с маршаллингом - Marshal.Copy(double[], Int32, IntPtr, Int32) считает, что массив по указателю IntPtr это double массив, но в данном случае это оказалось не так.